# Importing objects from another python file as a list

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a file (Crop_Library.py) containing a list of objects with various attributes (same number for all):

```
from Crop import Crop

Basil = Crop("Basil", 3, 0, 5, 10, 5)
Lettuce = Crop("Lettuce", 3, 4, 5, 10, 7)
Kale = Crop("Kale", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I would like for my GUI program (GUI.py) to read all the objects in Crop_Library.py and store them in a list so that my GUI can list them in a Combobox (so they also need to be converted to strings, or just read the crop.name string, which is the first attribute for all).

For now, importing is the question. However as an FYI, I would like to add edit functionality to another part of my GUI in the future such that the objects can be created/edited/deleted. I am open to using a json file instead of a python file to store these objects if that is a better approach - I am new to python and just very lost so any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JSON, what you read won't be Crop objects.  You could turn the input into Crop objects after reading the data.

Here's how you could have a list upon import of what you have:

```
from Crop import Crop

Basil = Crop("Basil", 3, 0, 5, 10, 5)
Lettuce = Crop("Lettuce", 3, 4, 5, 10, 7)
Kale = Crop("Kale", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

crops = [ Basil, Lettuce, Kale ]
```

or more concisely, if you don't need the object names, which you shouldn't...

```
from Crop import Crop

crops = [
    Crop("Basil", 3, 0, 5, 10, 5),
    Crop("Lettuce", 3, 4, 5, 10, 7),
    Crop("Kale", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,)
]
```

BTW, per proper Python naming conventions, your Crop object names should be lowercase.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the response! I'm still having trouble finding a way for my code to automatically create a list of just the crop names in that list of Crop objects. What I need at the moment is a list like in the last line of your first example, but created automatically since I will be adding the ability to edit/add/delete from that list, but need my combobox to read what is currently in that list of crops.

Comment: Look at Pickle.  Pickling is a way of serializing (turning into a stream of bytes) arbitrary Python objects rather than just dicts, lists and sets.  Check this out:  https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2016/12/object-serialization-in-python/?doing_wp_cron=1550454785.8881769180297851562500 . So you can have your user build up the list, and then Pickle it off to a datafile.  Then, when the user runs your app again, you can Unpickle the data file to reconstruct the in-memory list.

Comment: I don' know that it's the best way, but it wouldn't be too hard to write code that produced the equivalent of your Python input file we've been working with.  So you'd write special code to serialize your list as Python code, but then you'd just import the file to read it back in.  There are other ways to do this too.  A common way for robust apps is to have each of your objects know how to produce a serialized (stream of bytes or characters) representation of itself, and to be able to reconstruct itself from such a representation.

Comment: One specific way to do this last thing is to have your object be able to represent itself as an in-memory structure of lists, dicts, and sets.  Then the Python JSON library can be used to store and read back in that structure, and you would write code to turn that in-memory structure into your actual list of objects.   PS: If you can accept this answer so I can get some points, that would be great.

Comment: Hi Joe, I will go ahead and accept this and work through a few of your suggestions. Thanks a lot for all your input!